# How to make an image responsive after setting its height and width in bootstrap

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4, responsive-images

So I'm building this portfolio, and I found out ways to make the text and other stuff responsive, but I'm unable to make the picture responsive, I have set its height to 325, but when I shrink the page, the image isn't responsive. How should I make it responsive. The original image dimensions are around 1000 x 900, I tried shrinking the image size and using img-fluid but that didn't work as well.
[When I shrink the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0L65.png)
[When the page is in full view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7znl.png)

```
<img src="{% static 'shetha.jpg' %}" height="325  "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just should add static image URL. and if you have alt then you should add heigh or width or if you want both of them. but you must remove it. / <-- this 
if my answer help you check answered <3

```
<img src="{% static 'shetha.jpg' %}" alt="Smiley face" height="42" 
width="42">
```

Comment: plus alt is very good for Seo and you can create Charfield models and get alt information from database when you will upload image

Comment: didn't help. I want to set the height and make it responsive as well

Answer (score 0):

You can user this code too!

```
<img src="{% static 'shetha.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid"  "/>
```

Link:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/images/

Comment: I already tried that, using img-fluid bought my picture to its orginal size with is around 1000x900 and its covering thr entire page

Answer (score 0):

another answer for responsive image .and then you should add in CSS and make sure that responsive class not using something else
and load css file to html before head tag

HTML File

```
<img src="{% static 'shetha.jpg' %}" alt="Smiley face" 
class="responsive">
```

CSS file

```
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
```

if you want load css in html without creat css file
use this code before image.

```
<style>
.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
</style>
```

if you want load file do this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  </head>
  <body>
 <img src="{% static 'shetha.jpg' %}" alt="Smiley face" 
class="responsive">
  </body>
  </html>
```